# Fourier Expansion with period $4\pi$ and only odd indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm asked to obtain a Fourier series for the function

$$f(x) = x, [0, \pi]$$

in a fashion such that the period of the expansion is $4\pi$ and the expansion must be in sines with an $n$ such that $n = 2k -1$, as in only $b_{2k - 1}$ coefficients will appear.

I was given the result that

$$b_{2k-1} = \dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x) \cdot 
\sin(\dfrac{n\pi x}{2\pi})\,dx$$
but I'm having a bit of trouble.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Substitute in $f(x)=x$ here, then use integration by parts differentiating the $x$ in order to obtain your answer!

Comment: Hard to give a satisfactory answer without knowing what book you are reading. Could you please cite the reference?